# How do I force Xeround to close all connections?

Tags: mysql, connection, xeround

I was experimenting with SQLAlchemy on Xeround:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine("mysql://user:pass@instance0000.db.xeround.com.:1234/app000000")
>>> engine.execute("SELECT USER()").scalar()
>>> exit()
```

I did that a couple of times. Then I checked my Xeround management dashboard and it shows 2 connections. That was before I learned about:

```
>>> engine = create_engine("mysql://user:pass@instance0000.db.xeround.com.:1234/app000000")
>>> conn = engine.connect() # dashboard shows 3 connections
>>> conn.close() # dashboard still shows 3 connections
>>> exit() # after exiting, dashboard shows 2 connections
```

How do I force Xeround to close the remaining 2 connections (e.g. to forgive me for forgetting to close them)?

Comment: I'm also looking for the answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I force Xeround to close the remaining 2 connections (e.g. to forgive me for forgetting to close them)?

If you restart mysql service all works again like a charm, because your connections are not closed properly.
In this case, you need to use [A Connection Pool](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/pooling.html)